# How do I center my sonic image in a my container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How do I centre my image in the div container vertically as my align-item:center isn't working? I am currently learning how to use flex properties.I would be grateful if you all can help me

Besides the "alight item" problem, I think my codes looked a little messy and unclean, how can I improve it

```css
.outside{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

.container{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#3d7bcc,#2fedea);
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;


}

.image_container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

.paragraphs{
    margin-top: 50px;

}

.text{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="outside">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="image_container">
                    <img src="sonic.jpeg" alt="A photo of sonic">         
                </div>

                <div class="paragraphs">
                    <div class="text_1 text">
                        <p><b>Game:</b>Sonic the Hedgehog</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text_2 text">
                        <p><b>Year:</b>1991</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text_3 text">
                        <p><b>Platform:</b>SEGA</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you want to position your image? behind the paragraph? Things look right to me as per the code. align-items would center the image, but inside the `.image_container` and that div height is not enough to give you the center effect. increase the div height.

Comment: I agree the image cannot be vertically centered if it is same height as it's container. If you increase the height of the .image_container it should vertically align itself. However I would remove the height on the .container and let it adjust its own height based on it's children. This will save you some headache unless it's absolutely necessary that it's 400px

Comment: Furthermore I don't see you using the text_1, 2 or 3 classes so you can remove the divs surrounding the p tags since p tags are block level elements then add text align center to your .paragraph class which should give you the same result as it would cascade to the children.